# Pandas dataframe median of a column with condition

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, median

So I have a dataframe with two columns (price, location). Now I want to get the median of price, if the location is e.g. "Paris". How do I achieve that?

dataframe:

```
location   price    
paris       5    
paris       2    
rome        5    
paris       4
```

...

desired result: 4 (median of 2,5,4)

Comment: Please add an example of dataframe and expected output to the quesiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group on location, and then `.median()`:

```
median = df.groupby('location').median()
```

To get the value for each location:

```
median.loc['paris', 'price']
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: pd.groupby not exist

Comment: @athing what do you mean?

Comment: its pd.DataFrame.groupby you use not pd.groupby

Comment: @athing have changed. code is still correct

Comment: @skzy if so, could you press the tick and accept?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Build dataframe
data = [['Paris', 2], ['New York', 3], ['Rome', 4], ['Paris', 5], ['Paris', 4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['location', 'price'])

# Get paris only rows
df_paris = df[df['location'] == 'Paris']

# Print median
print(df_paris['price'].median())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).